# How to make requests work faster in python?

Tags: python, http, networking, python-requests

I'm using 2 libraries to make requests, and I need to get the LOWEST possible delay. Here's my first request code:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=request_data)
response = json.loads(response.text)['data']
```

Here's second request code:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host)
conn.request("POST", endpoint, payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
data = data.decode("utf-8")
data = json.loads(data)
```

I can't provide more data about this request, only can say that this requests are for binance. And also I already place my code on Tokio AWS, so I think it's the most optimal location already.

I want to know, maybe there are some hidden issues here that I can resolve to improve the delay? Also, maybe I should rewrite this code in C++? I don't think this will help at all, but how do you think?

Comment: Binance server's response isn't in your control, which will actually get assigned to your `response object`, because if they are observing latency at their end, no way you will get response early (thing to watch out for, irrespective of programming language). 
What is in your control is parsing the `json` response object and then consuming it. Can you share the benchmarks what you have been observing and what is target which you are striving for?

Comment: Now I getting 50ms for first request, and near 150ms for second request. And I want to achieve 100-150ms summary delay.
And I am sure that further processing is as effective as possible. Maybe is there way to parse json response faster?

Comment: May be you should take that as an exercise in exploring ways to parse and process JSON faster in a language agnostic way and see whether some optimisations can be done with respect to `json` module if required.